# variable declaration inside a function oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, toad

is their any thing wrong with this function ?. it is throwing invalid sql statement error.
im a newbee to oracle

```
create or replace function get_manager_names_str
(
   p_list in varchar2 := '793245567,65177897654'
)return varchar2 is
mgr_name varchar2(32767);

declare   -- i tried to remove the declare but still not working am i doing any thing wrong ?
mgr_id manager.manager_id%TYPE;
cursor split_values is 
select column_value from table (split_manager_list(p_list));  -- for testing you can test with                                                                                                                                                                     ---  some value

cursor manager_names is 
select * from manager 
where manager_id= mgr_id;

begin 
for r_split_values in split_values
loop
mgr_id := r_split_values.column_value;
dbms_output.put_line('splitvalue :'|| r_split_values.column_value);
for r_manager_names in manager_names
loop
mgr_name := mgr_name||r_manager_names.first_name || r_manager_names.last_name || r_manager_names.middle_name||'. ,' ;
end loop;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(mgr_name);
return mgr_name;
end; 
show errors;
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Added: split_list function to split the comma seperated values

```
Create or replace type split_tbl as table of varchar2(32767);
create or replace function split_manager_list
(
    p_list varchar2 ,
    p_del varchar2 := ','
) return split_tbl pipelined
is
    l_idx    pls_integer;
    l_list    varchar2(32767) := p_list;
    l_value    varchar2(32767);
begin
    loop
        l_idx := instr(l_list,p_del);
        if l_idx > 0 then

            pipe row( substr(l_list,1,l_idx-1));
            l_list := substr(l_list,l_idx+length(p_del));

        else
            pipe row( l_list);
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return;
end split_manager_list;
Show errors;
```

Comment: Is the assignment in the parameter section supposed to be a default, in case the function is called with no arguments?

Comment: No, its not default. it has to be passed as a parameter, for testing purpose i added a value

Comment: I want to declare                                                         mgr_id manager.manager_id%TYPE; as a local variable, how can i do that

Comment: Multisync rewrote it a bit faster than I did. You're only displaying (if your client has output turned on) and returning a single value, which isn't delimited so it'll be hard to do anything with. What do you want the caller of the function to get back? A collection of values perhaps? A ref cursor? It would also be better to pass in a collection rather than a string, particularly with lots of values - your caller could call your split function if needed.

Comment: Not sure if Toad understands `show errors`, but even if it does, that's a separate command and might be causing the invalid statement error? Depending on how you're running this, you might be missing a `/` after the final `end;` too.

Comment: / after end ? , i think toad will understand show errors. i might be wrong

Comment: ha ha the error is with show errors statment :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create or replace function get_manager_names_str (p_list in varchar2 default '793245567,65177897654') return varchar2 
is
  mgr_name varchar2(32767);
  mgr_id manager.manager_id%TYPE;
begin 
  for r_split_values in (select column_value from table (split_manager_list(p_list))) loop
    mgr_id := r_split_values.column_value;
    dbms_output.put_line('splitvalue :' || r_split_values.column_value);
    for r_manager_names in (select * from manager where manager_id = mgr_id) loop
      mgr_name := mgr_name || r_manager_names.first_name || r_manager_names.last_name || r_manager_names.middle_name || '. ,';
    end loop;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(mgr_name);
  return mgr_name;
end;
```

- used implicit cursors
- removed **declare**
- replaced := with DEFAULT
- reformated (easier to read and find mistakes)

The only problems I found are DECLARE + DEFAULT

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried that route by removing the declare,and added implicit cursors. but it is giving "invalid SQL statement" error.

Comment: @MustangManiac then your function split_manager_list does not return ref cursor. Show this function

Comment: hi @multisync i edited the code and added the split function code

Comment: @MustangManiac "split_manager_list" is OK. The function from my answer works fine in my env (I've created a table manager with requied fields)

Comment: hmm, that is weird. are you getting the comma seperated string ? on DBMsOUTPUT ?

Comment: @MustangManiac Does it play any role? I thought the problem is that your function is not compiling

Comment: it is compiling now the error is with show errors statement. im displaying the result in dbms_ouput but it is not showing the result in that tab. so how can we make sure that it is working ?/ where can we see the result ?

Comment: @MustangManiac Execute "select get_manager_names_str('test') from dual;"

Comment: is there a way to change the output grid column name ? it is printing the column name as get_manager_names_str('value'). I want my custom column name some thing like manager_names

Comment: @MustangManiac - use a column alias: `select get_manager_names_str('test') as manager_names from dual`

Comment: cool. im becoming dumb thats the basic one. thanks, @AlexPoole